# Difficulty taking off tap body to attempt to change washer

Tags: bathroom, faucet

Hi all to cut a long story short, had a dripping cold water tap, took the head off and am left with what you can see in the image, I have used some serious strength but am unable to turn the mechanism anti clockwise to take off so I can change the washer. Is there something I’m missing? Tried wd40 but no luck.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if one of our pros can help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It doesn’t look that bad, I have found a few that were left handed threads or turn CW to loosen but those were on flammable systems, but might be worth a try, also a hair dryer may be needed if lock tight was used on the threads, I am a big guy and have almost destroyed the brass prior trying heat or checking for left handed threads.

Comment: picture is not very clear, so it is hard to tell, but there may be a clip that you have to slide out sideways

Comment: "left handed threads or turn CW to loosen" the very definition of a left hand thread... @EdBeal

Comment: Get a proper spanner to fit, not an adjustable, and apply more force.

Comment: Try a 6-sided box-end wrench. Give the wrench handle a tap. If you can see any of the nut's threads you should be able to determine if it is a left or right thread.

Comment: @solar mike many people don’t remember how to tighten or loosen right handed threads and have never heard of left handed threads , this may sound silly explaining this but I found I had to state lefty loose righty tighty when teaching scuba classes to get many to know the correct direction. 
The op stated the correct direction for right handed but may knot have known about left handed or the possibility of locktight being used.

Comment: @EdBeal what knots are you on about? Or did you mean “not”?